# У кого есть бот телеграмм который принимает данные с формы и выводит их?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

Нужен телеграмм бот, который принимает данные с формы и выводит их. Буду благодарен)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого бота достаточно просто зарегистрировать и отправить ему команду /start.
Данные формы можно отправить в get или post запросе

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=<CHAT_ID>&text=Данные%20формы
```

Либо в тело запроса

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_TOKEN>/sendMessage
```

передать данные формы

```
{
    "chat_id": CHAT_ID,
    "text": "Имя: Василий\nФамилия: Чапаев"
}
```